# Dreamweaver different display than Firefox

Tags: html, css, webkit, dreamweaver, rendering-engine

I set up a simple example website to show you the issue that I'm currently fighting with:
http://examplesite.ohost.de/
In Firefox the site is rendering just fine, in the Dreamweaver, on my android phone and I think on other webkit browsers, the navigation bar buttons are cut off on the right and I think the buttons have slightly more width.
Here are some screenshots:
[image: screenshot]
[image]
So what do I have to change to get a similar result to the one in Firefox in every browser?

edit: 
I now tested it on the newest versions of Safari, Opera and Chrome and they are rendering it correctly.

Comment: I could not reproduce the problem on Firefox 28. On which version do you have the problem?

Comment: The problem doesn't exist in Firefox. I think you could reproduce this by using Safari or Opera. I haven't tried it though. A safe way to reproduce it is using the default browser on your android device or the program Dreamweaver.

Comment: Dreamweaver has its own "browser" to construct pages on the Dreamweaver "visual interface". That interface should only be used for "general structure". Always port the code to a page and read it with the browser of your choice.

Comment: @TimSPQR And how would that solve my problem? My issue is that some users won't see my site as they should. (for example android users)

Comment: This issue is a universal problem for all web programmers. You have to do the usual vendor prefixes moz, webkit. This page gives some guidelines (http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/excludecss.shtml). And a Google searching for "cross-browser support" will provide you with tons of info. If your most important aspect is mobile, then start with Android CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a fix size for navBtn, something like

```
.navBtn {
position: relative;
float: left;
line-height: 18px;
font-weight: bolder;
list-style: none outside none;
width: 100px;
}
```

This maintains element size.